# Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable

Tags: permissions, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my version of Wordpress but I get this error:

*Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a read-write permission error.  Fix this by changing the "wp-content" folder's permissions to **755**.

If this doesn't work checked the wp-config.php file and if it's not already defined, add

`define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');`

Comment: My temp dir was set to the wp-content/uploads folder and both plugin and Wordpress updates were failing. Changing it to the suggested value fixed it... not sure why, but thanks!

Comment: ran into this on mediatemple hosting and this worked perfectly

Comment: 755 wasn't enough - since my WP_TEMP_DIR was already set to wp-content/uploads I used `sudo chmod 775 wp-content/uploads`

Comment: I created a dummy folder 'wp-content/temp' so that any temporary files will not mess the wp-content directory.

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me for windows localhost!

Comment: In my case, I use duplicator to dupe the cloud copy to local for development. And found that in the wp-config is being modified with `WP_TEMP_DIR` set somewhere for the server. The duplicator just copy that also. For reference.

Comment: Solved my issue with using wordpress via docker and docker-sync. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

there are already `Define Temp` code in my `wp-config.php` file i just remove it and it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the temp directory is defined otherwise further down in the wp-config.php file, the later definition must either be changed to the above, or deleted.

This arose in my installation which started as a local Bitnami Wordpress install, but kept the same temp directory (pointing to my C: drive). I had placed the above code at the top of the file, but it was being superceded by the later temp folder definition that I was unaware of.